# Convert Jquery to Javascript (Converter Jquery para Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, typescript, frontend

I'm having a big problem. I'm not able to understand this jQuery code.

**How can I convert the following code to JavaScript.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#table").scroll(function() { 
        if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() == $(this).get(0).scrollHeight) {
            console.log("final")
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I don't think that plain js is more understandable.

Comment: Help Me, please!